# What kind of search algorithm could you use to solve this problem?

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search

Given an array of n integers A[0…n−1], such that ∀i,0≤i<n, we have that |A[i]−A[i+1]|≤1, and given x=A[0], y=A[n−1], we have that x<y. Locate, in O(log n), any index j such that A[j]=z, for a given value of z, x≤ z ≤y.

As I see it, the problem restricts that the -difference or "distance"- between the elements that are adjacent to each other is at most 1, but as I understand it, that does not mean that the array is ordered, it is true that there are sub-sequences, of any size, which can follow an ascending or descending order but precisely for this reason I do not see a clear way to use an algorithm that can search for the index in O(log n).

I was thinking of examples that would meet the constraints:

[1,2,1,2]

[-1,0,1,2,2,1,0,1,2,3]

[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,13,12,11,10]

[4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5]

I really don't know if I'm understanding the problem correctly :C.Could someone give me a hint please?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the array is not sorted, you can solve it similarly to [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), by checking in the middle (let it be `m`), and then:

1. If `z == m` - you are done.
2. If `z < m` - [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm): check on the first half of the array since `x <= z < m`
3. If `m < z` - divide and conquer: check on the second half of the array since `m < z <= y`

It is easy to prove this works by using the invariant that in each iteration `x <= z <= y`, and that the algorithm is guaranteed to end (since size is shrinking) - giving you a guaranteed end when `x == z == y` (at most).

Comment: Thank you very much, it still takes me a bit of work to understand why it doesn't affect in certain cases, but I think that the x<y restriction is precisely the one that helps a process similar to binary search to work.

Thanks so much for the explanation